# Many successful web startups have blue branding: is this a reflection of something?

Tags: color, color-theory

Looking at the first page of the most successful Web-based startups of the last 10 years (e.g., Facebook, Instagram, Twitter), we see the extensive usage of the color blue. In terms of the graphic design, is there any technical meaning behind the color blue (e.g., social interaction, trust, 'coolness')?; or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Blue is the colour of the mind, calmness, intelligence and coolness. And besides, it's a large part of all humans' favourite colour.

Comment: Interesting question. I remember hearing people in the '00s (pre-smartphones) suggest that blue is a good choice for social sites where your target audience would rather be outdoors under a blue sky with their friends rather than stuck indoors in front of a computer... but that's pretty speculative.

Comment: @Vincent I've never before heard Facebook and Instagram associated with "the mind, calmness, intelligence and coolness"... you must have a better calibre of friends than I do! :-) But yes, I'm sure these were qualities the site creators were hoping their users would express...

Comment: Another factor is that the color is trendy

Comment: @ZachSaucier Don't you think 10 years is too long for a trent to stay?

Comment: @DaveRose I don't think time has much of an effect on trends at all. Some companies, consciously or subconsciously, use the color because they trust the companies that have used it in the past

Comment: My opinion on why web startups use blue branding is that Twitter Bootstrap uses blue branding and those companies' Minimum Viable Products use Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Google, blue is:

> Blue is the color of the sky and sea. It is often associated with
>   depth and stability. It symbolizes trust, loyalty, wisdom, confidence,
>   intelligence, faith, truth, and heaven. Blue is considered beneficial
>   to the mind and body.

All good things, and generally things that companies want to be associated with. Here is a [neat article](https://medium.com/@byrnecore/why-do-so-many-brands-use-blue-as-their-base-colour-f3858c0ee986) that's asking the exact question as you. [Why do so many brands use Blue as their base colour?](https://medium.com/@byrnecore/why-do-so-many-brands-use-blue-as-their-base-colour-f3858c0ee986)

The article looks at a [study done by Emblemetric](http://www.emblemetric.com/2012/07/02/the-color-of-logos/) that traced the colors used in brands since the 90's. The study found that red had the lead in "most used color" until recently (about 2005), when blue overtook it. The author notes that while red denotes "passion and love", it also denotes "war and danger", things that social media (and other internet based companies) companies want to avoid.

Denoting power was something that companies wanted to do in the 90's to make people want their stocks. They largely ran operations behind closed doors, which was all well and good up until the internet came around. Now people could share the horror stories and companies can't sweep these reports under the rug. They're losing power, which is a red attribute. Now companies would rather show trustworthiness, loyalty, confidence, intelligence, truthfulness, stability and wisdom, all blue traits.

The internet is forcing new, more honest traits on companies, and the companies want to denote these traits to their customers as much as possible. Which is why so many of them are using blue as a base color.

Comment: What colors 'represent' is mostly bullshit. It sounds good, and can help 'sell' a logo in a client meeting, but almost every color can be found to have almost every meaning in some context.

Comment: Also, I have to -1 for "the internet is forcing new, more honest traits on companies". I can't buy into that at all. :)

Comment: @DA01 It's not bullshit as long as these associations aren't presented as some kind of metaphysical truth.  Researchers simply went out and studied the associations that people already have with colors, and there are designers who specialize in applying that knowledge.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede the associations people have with color are heavily dependent on context. Asking random people what associations they  make with color aren't all that useful outside the context of the logo that is being worked on.

Comment: @DA01 You should see, that is irrelevant if the meaning of colors is total BS. If the companies belief that blue means honesty and people want honesty, then this is the right answer why so many companies chose blue - because they think it makes them look honest. If that is actually true, or a scam by designers is not mentioned and not relevant for this answer.

Comment: @DA01 I disagree. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_psychology#Brand_meaning

Comment: @Falco scam? I don't know what you are arguing. Whether something is true or not, I argue, is certainly a part of a good answer.

Comment: @Nagoshi I didn't say color wasn't important. It is, of course *very important*. But what makes it important isn't 'color psychology' as much as overall color *theory*, aesthetics, competitive analysis, etc.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede my point is that with 'careful research' you could prove any color means anything. It's not science--just surveys and opinions. Hence why I tend to put it on the BS side of the fence.

Comment: @DA01 I don't understand what you don't understand.  It's certainly possible to scientifically study people's opinions, no matter how irrational those opinions might be.  And it's certainly possible to apply the knowledge gained from that research to manipulate people's responses to advertising.  That is the subject of this Q&A.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede my quibble is the "according to google...". There is no universal 'truth' to what each and every color means generically. That is what I'm calling BS on. Yes, people claim colors mean all sorts of things, but so what? What matters is the particular logo being designed and the particular needs of the business and the particular impressions of the target audience. Now, that *particular* audience may have color preferences, and if they can be measured, sure, but that's something *entirely* different than just saying "blue means depth and stability"

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No, you cannot scientifically study peoples' opinions.  There is nothing falsifiable about an individual's subjective opinion outside of the truth values of factual statements subsumed by that opinion.

Comment: @K.AlanBates A person's opinion is an opinion, but the fact that they hold that opinion and how they came to that opinion are facts which can be scientifically studied.  I don't see what's so hard to grasp about this.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Again, opinions cannot be scientifically studied specifically because opinions cannot be placed in ceteris paribus conditions and no hypothesis about those opinions are falsifiable due to each and every individual opinion being formed in the  unique context of the individual that holds them and each is universally subjective.  There may be a kernel of a particular opinion that has a truth value to it, but you cannot study human action scientifically; praxeology does not work that way. You can *study* opinions *philosophically*, but you cannot study them *scientifically*.

Comment: @K.AlanBates The falsifiable hypotheses are things like "Joe Shmoe holds opinion X" or "23.5% of the population holds opinion Y".  These kinds of facts can most certainly be studied scientifically, and their study has practical applications such as the color theory being discussed here.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I'm belaboring the point now, so this will be my last comment in here. What you have proposed in your comment immediately above mine is not science. There is more to science than "observation and study." As I said, you can study all of these things philosophically, but there is no way to hold them up to the rigor of the Scientific Method which is a tacit requirement for calling any process "scientific." What you are discussing is much, much, much too "soft."

Comment: @K.AlanBates That's a matter of opinion. ;)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede you are correct that you can figure out if 20% of people thinks blue = stability. But you can't scientifically prove that blue means stability. And for that matter, the opinion of 20% of random people isn't good data for the specifics of a particular logo. At best, you can perhaps to A/B testing with a very defined target audience, but to pull random "X% think color Y = Z" is, IMHO, BS. Sometimes effective and useful BS, but BS nonetheless.

Answer (score 15):

It's a reflection that a lot of logos are blue is all. Blues and Reds tend to be the popular colors these days. And, really, they've been popular colors for logos for a long time.

[image]

In addition, I'm not sure what you define as a successful web startup, but note that today's startup world is mostly a bunch of people pumping out as many ideas as they can as fast as they can hoping one of them sticks. There's not necessarily a ton of thought going into these brands identities out of the gate. A lot of it is 'copy the last successful idea and then move on to the next'.

I'm not saying there's plagiarism or anything like that, but there's not likely a whole lot of 'color psychology' involved. It's more likely "Blue? Blue is nice. Sure, go with that. Done."

Comment: Even if it’s not part of the design intention, color psychology can still be part of what determines which logos are more effective, and hence which brands tend to succeed.

Answer (score 12):

Can't speak for your other two examples, but according to a [New Yorker article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/09/20/the-face-of-facebook) written in 2010, Mark Zuckerberg chose blue for Facebook not for any technical meaning or symbolism in the color but because he is red-green colorblind, and as he said in that article, “Blue is the richest color for me; I can see all of blue.”

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. Most logos are chosen simply because it's someone's favorite color. In fact, the better logos (not saying Facebook is in that group) can work with almost any color. Picking a particular color just ads to the brand cohesiveness.

Comment: Pretty sure that it answers the question as "coincidence", at least for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

This may also reflects founder's perception on their business strategy. Wheter they are aware or not.

There are 2 terms in business related to those colors: blue / red ocean strategy.
Blue means that business focuses on creating completely innovative and new things, whereas Red Ocean Strategy means that company is putting all its energy into augmenting services or products that are already delivered by someone else - basically it more about fighting against it's competitors.

I think that some of those colors in brands logos may have origin in this - at least when it comes to blue color.

More info: 
http://www.blueoceanstrategyaustralia.com.au/what-is-bos/red-vs-blue/

Comment: Hi mrkf, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I don't see what those two consultant terms have to do with color theory.

Answer (score -1):

I have read research that says that casinos use reds and warm colors at the entrance to attract people, but use blues and cool colors inside to get them to stay longer.  If it does have that effect, it may be another reason social media sites choose blue.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the research?